# Same rules, different prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my project, there are two kinds of files, both created using the same commands, but with prerequisites:

```
%.blvp: lab_bd.act %.ext
%.slvp: lab_syn.act %.ext

%.blvp %.slvp:
    $(eval x := $(basename $@))
    act2lvp $< $x
    lvp -sDEv $x.ext $x.prs && touch $@
```

The only difference is that `.blvp` files use `lab_bd.act` and `.slvp` use `lab_syn.act`. Whichever file this is is meant to be the first argument to `act2lvp`.

However, the prerequisites from above do not get carried down into the rule (i.e., `act2lvp  $x` is evaluated; `$^` is apparently empty.

```
$ make xyz.slvp
act2lvp  xyz
Usage: /usr/local/cad/bin/act2lvp  <actfile> <processname>
makefile:17: recipe for target 'xyz.slvp' failed
make: *** [xyz.slvp] Error 1
```

How can I get the prerequisites to be carried down from above? Alternatively, would you suggest an alternative approach for this circumstance?

Comment: Just to be clear: your first two lines are no-ops.  A pattern rule _must_ have a recipe, otherwise it's interpreted as deleting that pattern rule.  Also a note: using `eval` (or `shell`) inside a recipe is generally an anti-pattern.  It's almost never really the best way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern rules don't combine that way, but you can get the same effect with a [pattern-specific variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern_002dspecific):

```
%.blvp: ACT=lab_bd.act
%.slvp: ACT=lab_syn.act

%.blvp %.slvp : %.ext
    $(eval x := $(basename $@))
     act2lvp $(ACT) $x
     lvp -sDEv $x.ext $x.prs && touch $@
```

**P.S.** you can save yourself some trouble with the [automatic variable `$*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
%.blvp %.slvp : %.ext
     act2lvp $(ACT) $*
     lvp -sDEv $*.ext $*.prs && touch $@
```

**EDIT:** I overlooked the task of rebuilding the *.act files. We can add `$(ACT)` as a prerequisite if we use [Secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.blvp %.slvp : %.ext $$(ACT)
     act2lvp $(ACT) $*
     lvp -sDEv $*.ext $*.prs && touch $@
```

Comment: I suspected `basename` wasn't the best way to do that. `$*` was exactly what i was looking for to solve that problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: However, with this setup, are the `*.act` files actually dependencies anymore? Will make recompile if one of those files change?

Comment: What about defining those variables with wildcards? Is there a way to do `%.xyz: FILE=%.abc`?